# Server Architecture/Automatic Deployment - How to set up a SAAS web application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, cloud, saas, software-distribution

I wrote a web application, and I would like to sell it as software-as-a-service. I'm using Amazon Web Services to host the production environment, currently.

I'm hosting the applications internally on clients servers/intranet, or having them sign up for Amazon to purchase their own EC2/RDS containers.

This setup process takes forever in that there are several manual steps involved in working like this. I have to set up the entire stack. I setup an EC2 & RDS instance, setup Route53, pull the source from git, run migrations, setup chron, and finally let nginx know that the site is up.

## The Issue

Ideally, I'd like for users to be able to go to the website, sign up, and have access to their own implementation of this application. I'd like to automate this process. They should then be able to access the application via a url structured like so:
**customername.primary-domain.com**

You can see this happening in many applications utilizing *'the cloud'*. For example, Office365/Sharepoint will spin up a customers own version of that application.

I'd like this to be shared hosting, in that there are several clients on an EC2 instance.

## Questions

- How can I accomplish this in a reasonable, affordable way?
- What software options are there to solve this?
- What are some different options other than the 3 I have listed here?
- For the VM option, what is good to use? Docker, Vagrant? What are other options?
- What are these companies using to do this? How is Salesforce, Microsoft, or any of you automating this?

## Thoughts on how to accomplish this

I know very little about this topic. I did some brain storming about what I already know (basically nothing involving any scale) and I came up with the following ways I could think of to accomplish this:

## Application Level Switching

[image]

A user would sign up, and all the records they create will have a foreign key to their profile. This seems like the easiest approach, but I don't believe it would scale very well, not to mention a terrifying security risk. I'd like to keep client's data as isolated as possible.

## Web Server Approach

[image]

When a user signs up, an external process will create a folder on the web server and pull the application source code, and run database migrations. This script would create the corresponding records with nginx. This seems like the easiest to manage and support and scale, however I dislike that there is a shared database sever.

## Virtualization

[image]

Use Docker or Vagrant (Which is best? Are there other options?) to run multiple production-ready installations on the EC2 instance. This could allow me to ship with MySQL installed on the container, removing the need for a global MySQL install, or RDS entirely. This feels like the most attractive option, but seems like the trickiest to set up, in that it seems very technical, and potentially a nightmare to support.

edit:
You could decouple the database from the application and run the DB in a different container than the application. This is probably the best way to do this but seems even more of an advanced setup. Is there something which already does this?

### Summary

Cloud wizards, please help me understand your magic.

Comment: The answer appears to be docker. I just had some trouble wrapping my head around how this fits together, but I think I got it. I will follow up with an answer once I get everything set up.

Comment: Why do you want to start a separate EC2 instance for every client? Do you have such nonfunctional requirement?